# -You are losers! - Who are losers!? We?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, interrogatives

If two group of people meet each other and someone says:

*You are losers!*

Will it be correct if he will be answered like

*Who **are** losers!? We? Naaah, you are!*

Or it should be said like a singular form

*Who **is** loser!? We? Naaah, you are!* ?

Comment: If both sides are groups, the plural is appropriate. In an informal exchange like this, the second group would almost certainly say 'Us?' rather than 'We?'.

Comment: So, "we" isn't gramatically incorrect, it just sounds too official? Like, some deputies' meeting, not a gangstars' one?

Comment: The 'correct' version would be _We [are]_, but no-one having a shouting match in the street would say it like that!

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't call the group of people a loser, you would say that the members of the group are losers, so you must use *are*.

It sounds very formal to use *we?* when you can use *us?*, and this is probably not a formal situation.

For these reasons, you should say:

> Who are [the] losers? Us? Nah, you are [the losers]!

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, using "we" is formal while "us" is informal?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Well, they usually play different roles in sentences, and are not always interchangeable. In this context, you are correct. It sounds informal because you wouldn't say "Us are losers", but it's widely understood and more common with this sentence structure.

Comment: The "Us?" fragment doesn't seem to represent "Are us losers?"  More likely, the ellipsis represents "[Are they] us?" or "[Is it] us [who are losers]?".  Once upon a time, "this is he" was taught as a formally correct response to something like "I'd like to speak to John Smith."  Common responses today include "that's me" and "I'm him", and using the subjective case for the argument of a copular verb generally appears not merely formal but pretentious.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan That's true, I didn't think of it like that.